# Do I use combinations or permutations when calculating the probability of something happening?

Tags: probability

Alexander runs a doggy daycare, where 11 dogs are currently enrolled. The collection of dogs includes 4 of Alexander's favourite type of dog, golden retrievers.

If Alexander randomly picks 7 dogs to play in the park during the first time slot, what is the probability that exactly 3 of the chosen dogs are golden retrievers?

Write your answer as a decimal rounded to four decimal places.

Comment: Hey! What progress have you made? Where have you got stuck?

Comment: I don't understand why you use combinations for this question.

Comment: Call a combo of $7$ dogs *good* if there are exactly three golden retrievers. We want the probability of Alex picking a good combination. One way is to count the total number of good combinations, then divide by the total number of combinations of $7$ dogs (without any restrictions).

Comment: A permutation is something where the order matters. Some $abc$ and $bac$ are different *permutations* but the same *combination*. In this particular case, it doesn't really matter the order in which Alexander picks out the dogs; what matters is what dogs gets picked. So you look at the combinations and not the permutations. Although perhaps the dog that gets picked last gets its feelings hurt :p

Answer (score 0):

> Do I use combinations or permutations when calculating the probability of something happening?

Typically, such a problem is best solved by expressing the probability as

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$

Here, the most critical point is that **whichever** approach that you use, you must be **consistent** re computing $N$ and computing $D$.  That is, if $N$ is computed as the total # of favorable *combinations* (rather than permutations), then $D$ **must** be computed as the total number of possible combinations.

Factors that I consider when choosing whether to use permutations or combinations:

- Whichever is easiest.  If for example, computing $D$ as permutations is immediate, without much thought, that will influence me.  However, I sometimes will choose a moderately harder choice for $D$ (e.g. combinations instead of permutations), if it significantly eases the computation of $N$ (as combinations instead of permutations).
- Whichever facilitates mutually exclusive cases, or helps avoid *over-counting*.  This issue is tricky, varies from problem to problem, often requires creativity, and is too broad a subject to detail here.  I will simply say that this issue can easily affect my choice of whether to use permutations or combinations.
- Whichever approach promotes elegance.  Sometimes, I will be able to visualize an approach (either combinations or permutations) that simplifies computing $N$ and $D$ consistently, and avoids delving into sub-cases.  In such a situation, I will opt for elegance because it significantly reduces the analysis/computations required.